# Laravel [9] html sometimes does not render properly

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-9

Actually this problem i noticed a have few weeks ago.

I using Docker for Windows and laravel running on docker.

I tried using local and remote database, but nothing has changed.

What is the problem? I cant detect anything.

This page is look like good rendered. But if i change page or reload, any place is look like this in page. I tried some things but didnt work.

[image: This is a normal page]

Not every time, just sometimes :/

[image: This is wrong page 1]

[image: This is wrong page 2]

list.blade.php

```html
@extends('admin.layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Tüm Siparişler')
@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="search-box me-2 mb-2 d-inline-block">
                                <div class="position-relative">
                                    <form method="GET" action="{{ route('admin_order_status', $status) }}">
                                        <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control"
                                            value="{{ $search }}" placeholder="Arama...">
                                        <i class="bx bx-search-alt search-icon"></i>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table align-middle table-nowrap table-check">
                            <thead class="table-light">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 20px;" class="align-middle">
                                        <div class="form-check font-size-16">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkAll">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checkAll"></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="align-middle">ID</th>
                                    <th class="align-middle">Ürün</th>
                                    <th class="align-middle">Müşteri</th>
                                    <th class="align-middle">Fiyat</th>
                                    <th class="align-middle">Sonraki ödeme tarihi</th>
                                    <th class="align-middle">Durum</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($orders as $item)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-check font-size-16">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                                                    id="orderidcheck{{ $item->order_id }}">
                                                <label class="form-check-label"
                                                    for="orderidcheck{{ $item->order_id }}"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ route('admin_order_view', $item->order_id) }}"
                                                class="text-body fw-bold">
                                                {{ $item->order_id }}
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ route('admin_order_view', $item->order_id) }}"
                                                class="text-body fw-bold">
                                                {{-- @lang("admin/orders.type.{$item->data->product_name}") --}}
                                                {{ $item->data->product_name }}
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ route('admin_users_summary', $item->user_id) }}">
                                                {{ $item->first_name }} {{ $item->last_name }}
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ $item->amount }} ₺
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="fw-bold">
                                            @if ($item->next_paid_at)
                                                {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->next_paid_at) }}
                                            @else
                                                -
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span
                                                class='badge badge-pill bg-{{ config("enums.order_status_color.$item->status") }} font-size-12'>
                                                @lang("admin/orders.$item->status")
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    {!! $orders->withQueryString()->links() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



@endsection
```

Controller.php

```php
class OrdersController extends Controller
{

    public function indexByStatus(Request $request, string $status = 'all')
    {

        $search = $request->get('search');

        $orders = Order::query();
        $orders = $orders->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id');

        $orders = $orders->select([
            'users.id as user_id',
            'users.first_name',
            'users.last_name',
            'orders.id as order_id',
            'orders.amount',
            'orders.data',
            'orders.payment_method',
            'orders.invoice_id',
            'orders.status',
            'orders.next_paid_at',
        ]);

        if ($search) {
            if ($status != 'all') {
                $orders->where('orders.status', $status);
            }
            $orders->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                return
                    $q->orWhere('users.first_name', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                    ->orWhere('users.last_name', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                    ->orWhere('orders.data', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
            });
        } else {
            if ($status != 'all') {
                $orders->where('orders.status', $status);
            }
        }

        $orders = $orders->orderByDesc('orders.created_at');
        $orders = $orders->paginate(10);

        return view(
            'admin.orders.allorders',
            [
                'orders' => $orders,
                'search' => $search,
                'status' => $status,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Model.php

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'status',
        'payment_method',
        'billing_period',
        'data',
        'user_id',
        'invoice_id',
        'amount',
        'next_paid_at',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'object',
        'next_paid_at' => 'timestamp',
        'created_at' => 'timestamp',
        'updated_at' => 'timestamp'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what your data looks like but it does look like  the HTML tags are improperly closed at some point. I would suggest to inspect your page HTML source to find any places where the input gets messed up. Particularly suspicious is seeing `metisMenu.min.js` in plaintext which indicates that at some point the (presumably) `<script src="...` tag was closed prematurely

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry `metisMenu.min.js` is just an example. If the same error was shown every time, I'd say you're right. There is no change in the 3 images above, I just click to f5 in the page and boom sometimes. All tags are closed :/